# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I tried to use `categories` instead of `categorical_features`, but it did not help.

Please help with the error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "test.py", line 28, in <module>                                                                                      onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])                                                             TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X=LabelEncoder()
X[:,0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:,0]) #Encoding the values of column Country

onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[0])

X=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
print(X)
```

Comment: can you please post the complete error block?

Comment: The constructor of `OneHotEncoder` of recent versions does not support the argument `categorical_features`. Versions up to 0.19 do. See the documentation: [recent](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), [old](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).

Comment: @WSMathias9 I have edited answer. Please check it.

Comment: What happened when you tried with `categories`?

Comment: @Guym then I get such error: `ValueError: Shape mismatch: if categories is an array, it has to be of shape (n_features,).`

Comment: @abby that error message sounds like a progress over the outright invalid-argument error. I think there's nothing wrong with the `categories` part itself.

Comment: @Jin-ohKang where can be problem? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Acc to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) their is not any attribute 'categorical_features'

> categories‘auto’ or a list of array-like, default=’auto’
> Categories (unique values) per feature:
>
> ‘auto’ : Determine categories automatically from the training data.
>
> list : categories[i] holds the categories expected in the ith column. The passed >categories should not mix strings and numeric values within a single feature, and should >be sorted in case of numeric values.
>
> The used categories can be found in the categories_ attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

...
X = ...

# Encoding the values of column Country
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
X = np.concatenate(
    onehotencoder.fit_transform(X[:,0:1]),
    X[:,1:],
    axis=1
)
print(X)

# Do this to show what categories are collected and encoded.
print(onehotencoder.categories_)
```

The old version of scikit-learn did all the projection, encoding and re-merging, sinking non-categorical columns to the right. It doesn't support it now, so we instead extract the `Country` column manually, pass it through the encoder, and concatenate them together.

`OneHotEncoder` by default returns "sparse" arrays, and we can avoid converting them into numpy arrays by specifying `sparse=False`.

Note that `LabelEncoder` is redundant since `OneHotEncoder` can automatically fit to string values anyway (at least in recent versions).